# Page access token validity

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

From the facebook Document-
By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring user access token obtained through the deprecated offline_access permission.

So according to document a page access will not expires if we are requesting the page access token using a long lived user access token.

I want to know whether the page access token will expire as the long lived access token expires?

**What happens to the page access token obtained using long lived access token after the long lived access token has been expired (after 60 days)?**

Comment: When we debug the long lived access token, the expiry date is never but it expires in a duration of 60 days, likewise when we debug page access token it says, it expires never. So i want to make sure the page access token is life long before i can go for development.
Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Forget stuff that you acquired using offline_access, and get a _new_ token. Everything else is most likely not reliable.

Comment: I got new long lived token and generated page access token. I am just concerned about the validity of the generated page access token.

Comment: _“I am just concerned about the validity of the generated page access token.”_ – you said the debug tool already told you that the page access token would _not_ expire – so what are we discussing about here?